# why does this alert fire before earlier code has finished executing?

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code which executes when a link is clicked.

after that code has executed I want to display an alert, however the alert is being shown before the earlier code completes

```
document.querySelector('.btn-primary').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

    var loops = 10;
    var chunkLength = Math.ceil(file.size / loops);
    var start = 0;
    var stop = chunkLength;

    for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        var blob = file.slice(start, stop);
        readText(blob);
        start = stop;
        stop += chunkLength;
    }
    alert('entire file loaded');
    print();
}, false);
```

### updates

I know because the readText method updates a progress bar and this happens after the alert pops up, its not an ajax call just a local method *(which is asynchronous...)*

eventually, I'm looking to replace the alert with a call to save a file but its no use if the file content hasn't been generated yet as I just save an empty file.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: Is `readText` by change ajax related?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Its not an ajax call but it is an asynchronous method. so i guess thats the problem. I suppose my question ought to be how to use a callback function when not doing ajax...

Comment: so i guess it is ajax just without the xml part...

Comment: It would probably a lot easier to answer your question if you'd share the implementation of the `readText` function. Or at least the bits of it that are relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you'll need to extend `readText` to accept a callback function:

```
function readText(blob, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = callback;
    // whatever else your function does to load the file
}
```

Then you invoke it like this:

```
readText(blob, function() {
    alert('entire file loaded');
});
```

Of course if `readText` itself delegates its asynchronous work somewhere else, you'll have to pass the callback there too.

If the actual asynchronous function doesn't accept a callback parameter, you'll want to check for another way that it signals its caller of completeness. It may fire events. But that all really depends on how `readText` is implemented.

Comment: `readText`is basically a wrapper for the `FileReader.readAsText(blob)`I don't think it accepts a callback but I can look it up - thanks!

Comment: `FileReader.readAsText` indeed doesn't have a callback.. But `FileReader` has on onload event that you can hook into. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.onload

I'll see if I can update my code snippets with that knowledge.

Comment: unfortunately multiple onload events are fired (one for each chunk loaded) and theres no way of telling which one is the last one. So i'll need to think of something else. I might only show a save button once the progress bar is fully loaded

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that `readText` is an asynchronous method. This is why the `alert` shows before `readText` has finished executing. The `for` loop will run through all its iterations by which time calls to `readText` have not finished. The next statement to execute after the `for`, is the `alert` which is what you're seeing.

If `readText` provides a callback function, you will have to use that:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    var blob = file.slice(start, stop);
    readText(blob, function() {
        counter++;
        if(counter === loops) {
            alert("entire file loaded");
        }
    });
    start = stop;
    stop += chunkLength;
}
```

This doesn't guarantee order of operations however. It is entirely possible that a call on a later iteration finishes before a call from an earlier iteration.

If `readText` doesn't have a callback argument and you can modify the source of that function, you will have to do something like this:

```
function readText(blob, callback) {
    ...

    if(typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
```