# Javascript alert() supersedes preceding code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a contact form with a submit button. I am using JQuery to do the following in exactly the following order once a response is received from the server-side PHP that processes the submitted data:

1. Change button text to "Send"
2. Display the received response in an alert

The code is straightforward:

```
submit_button.text('Send');
alert(response);
```

However, the `alert()` always seems to trigger *before* the text change no matter what. Is this by design? Any trick to alter the sequence? I need the button's text to change *before* the alert is displayed. I even tried the following in vain:

```
submit_button.text('Send');
if(submit_button.text() == 'Send') { alert(response); }
```

I'm sorry if this question has already been answered elsewhere and request you to point me in the right direction should that be the case.

Comment: why would you need to use a native alert in the first place? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The alert is there to tell the user if the email was sent and why if not. The prototype is live at peppyburro.com/sandboxindex if you need to see it live. Just click HELP->CONTACT US from the navbar menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why does this alert fire before earlier code has finished executing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869275/why-does-this-alert-fire-before-earlier-code-has-finished-executing)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082452/javascript-alert-box-shows-up-before-executing-previous-statement

Comment: Simple solution is don't use alert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript alert box shows up before executing previous statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082452/javascript-alert-box-shows-up-before-executing-previous-statement)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap your `alert` call into a `setTimeout` call, that will put the `alert` call at the end of the event loop and will give time for the browser to update the DOM first.

```
submit_button.text('Send');
setTimeout(function () { alert(response); }, 1);
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/sn9cbqz3/3/

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it by 40 seconds!

Comment: Since technically 1ms may not be sufficient to update the button text on some old systems, you can also 'literally' wait for it to change then display the alert with : 
  submit_button.text('Send');
  while(submit_button.text()!='Send');
  alert('test');

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the script continues without giving DOM the time to update. You can use `setTimeout` to achieve what you want:

```
submit_button.text('Send');
setTimeout(function(){
      alert(response);
},10);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this can be solved with a `setTimeout` to allow the browser to complete the thread and repaint, before the alert is triggered, like this...

```
submit_button.text('Send');
setTimeout(function() {alert(response);},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As respondent in [Javascript alert box shows up before executing previous statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16082623)

> Changes in the browser doesn't show up as long as your Javascript code is running.
>
> The browser is event driven, so changing an element in the DOM doesn't show the change immediately, instead an event is triggered to redraw the element. When your function has finished running, the browser will handle any pending events and show the changes.
>
> So, when building an application, you have to use the same approach so that the browser has a chance to show the changes.
> [By Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082452/javascript-alert-box-shows-up-before-executing-previous-statement)

The timeout suggestions are pretty much your best bet.

```
submit_button.text('Send');
setTimeout(function () { alert(response); }, 1);
```

Suggested by [Rik Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593106/rik-lewis)